# getResource() returns null when run code in gitlab pipeline and target directory is empty

Tags: java, gradle, nullpointerexception, resources

I have an empty folder emptyFolder. When I run code locally (gradle) it works

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(emptyFolder)
```

But when I run the same code in gitlab pipeline it returns null

All tasks before the running are the same

```
> Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :cleanTest
> Task :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :test
```

At the same time if I put any file in emptyFolder it works in gitlab pipeline as well. Looks like the issue happens when I use getResource() for empty directory only. But why I do not have the same issue during the local running?
Could somebody help me to understand?

Comment: Somebody else's machine and application configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the directory created in the pipeline? Git does not track empty directories so it could be caused by that empty directory exists on local computer but is never created on the machine where pipeline is running.

Comment: Omg. Yeah, you are right. I've checked the repository in the gitlab and it doesn't have my empty folder.